# Show glow when a button is touched

Tags: ios, button

Trying to use an info button in an iOS app. Wondering if anyone knows how to simulate the glow effect when you click on it.

See for example the weather or stocks apps in an iPhone; when you touch it, their is a glow highlight around the touch. Touch and hold to see it.

Comment: What did you try yourself? What did you search, show some example code...

Comment: I have simply added an info button from the storyboard. Just a UIButton with Type Info Dark. But that does not give you the light effect.

Comment: @user1845360 add some code of Button OR set your UIButton Type is InfoDark .

Comment: Reworded the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIButton has a property called `showsTouchWhenHighlighted`. By default this is set to `NO`.

If you set it to yes you will get the glow effect when the button is highlighted.

You can set this in Interface builder by checking the "Shows Touch on Highlight" option.

Or you can do it in code with:

```
infoButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

This applies to all UIButtons, not just to info ones.

Comment: Have you tried that, because it does not work for me.

Comment: If you are adding button through interface builder and setting the type to info light,  IB will automatically check `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` check box

Comment: @user1845360 What doesn't work for you? Setting it in IB or setting it in code? Because this works perfectly well for me. Are you showing it on a dark background? because it's not very visible on light backgrounds.

Comment: Its not working for both cases..will try in a dark background. The button is dark so I would expect to see something even in a white background.